# World Baseball Classic: Pool with three-way tie

Tags: tie-breaker, postseason, world-baseball-classic

Considering round-robin play, where each team play another in its bracket once:

How would the following three-way tie be resolved:

**Pool X**

```
Team A 2-1
Team B 2-1
Team C 2-1
Team D 0-3
```

In this scenario, each of the teams with 2 wins beat Team D once, and beat one of the other two teams.  For the sake of argument,

```
Team A beat Team B
Team B beat Team C
Team C beat Team A
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tiebreakers for the World Baseball classic in a three way tie are as follows. These steps would determine the first place team which would automatically advance to the next round and then the 2nd and 3rd place team would play a one game playoff to determine the 2nd team to advance. 
The tiebreakers are,
1.) Fewest runs allowed per inning of defense in head-to-head games 
2.)Fewest earned runs allowed per inning of defense in head-to-head games
3.)Highest batting average in head-to-head games
4.)Drawing of lots